# Rails.root being overwritten by Amazon AWS-SDK gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rubygems

I see this error:

```
undefined method `root' for AWS::Rails:Module
```

The corresponding line in my controller:

```
directory_name = Rails.root.join('public', @curAdmin.name)
```

This worked fine until I recently added the aws-sdk gem to my application to push static files and assets over to my S3 bucket.

Now it seems like when I call "Rails" the application thinks I'm referring to an AWS class method.

I don't know how I tripped the system up to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you refer to `Rails` within the `AWS` namespace. You should be able back out of the namespace by prepending `::` to the module - ie `::Rails.root.join('public', @curAdmin.name)`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.  I got rid of the include AWS line to remove the namespace and refer to AWS class methods with AWS::S3::FOO and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I tripped everything up - but if I remove the include at the top of the controller:

```
#include AWS
```

And then I refer to such methods directly as:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets['my_bucket_here']
```

It works ok.  I'd still like to know what I did wrong.